# Angular: call method when async img is fully loaded

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently working on an image view, where you can zoom into a picture and move it around in a container. So because the images have all different sizes, I want to call a method, that calculates the size of the container, with the format of the loaded picture. But I have to wait, until the image ist fully loaded, because it is loaded with async. When I resize the browser window, everything works fine and the container is resized as it should.
This is how I load the picture (html template):

```html
<div
  (mousewheel)="onMousewheel($event)"
  id="img-holder"
  [ngStyle]="{'height': containerHeight+'px', 'width': containerWidth+'px'}"
>
  <img
    *ngIf="currentItem"
    id="img"
    [attr.src]="(currentItem.parent_dir + currentItem.name | image: repoId : 1024) | async"
    alt="{{currentItem.name}}"
    [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'scale('+zoomLevel+')', 'top': curY+'px', 'left': curX+'px'}"
    (mousedown)="mousedown($event)"
    #img
  />
</div>
```

and i want to call the onResize Method here (component.ts):

```js
@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
onResize($event?) {
  if (this.img) {
    this.setContainerBounds(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth);
  }
}

setContainerBounds(screenHeight: number, screenWidth: number) {
  const imgWidth = this.img.nativeElement.width;
  const imgHeight = this.img.nativeElement.height;
  const format = imgHeight / imgWidth;
  this.containerWidth = screenWidth / 2;
  this.containerHeight = this.containerWidth * format;
  console.log(
    "height: " + this.containerHeight + ", widht: " + this.containerWidth
  );
}
```

And this is the pipe:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: "image",
})
export class ImageRequestPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private librariesService: LibrariesService) {}

  transform(
    value: string,
    argRepoId: string,
    argSize?: number
  ): Observable<string | ArrayBuffer> {
    return new Observable<string | ArrayBuffer>((observer) => {
      this.librariesService
        .getThumbnail(argRepoId, value, argSize)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(response);
          reader.onloadend = function () {
            observer.next(reader.result);
          };
        });

      return {
        unsubscribe() {},
      };
    });
  }
}
```

I tried to work with `onResize` as a callback function for the pipe, but i failed... Maybe someone knows how to solve this the best way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really short solution for this: I added the (load) attribute to the img with my `onResize` method as an argument... Now the html looks like this:

```html
<div
  (mousewheel)="onMousewheel($event)"
  id="img-holder"
  [ngStyle]="{'height': containerHeight+'px', 'width': containerWidth+'px'}"
>
  <img
    *ngIf="currentItem"
    id="img"
    [attr.src]="(currentItem.parent_dir + currentItem.name | image: repoId : 1024) | async"
    alt="{{currentItem.name}}"
    [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'scale('+zoomLevel+')', 'top': curY+'px', 'left': curX+'px'}"
    (load)="onResize()"
    (mousedown)="mousedown($event)"
    #img
  />
</div>
```